# pulling and using current data in the dataset

Tags: r

```
 df <- read.csv ('https://raw.githubusercontent.com/ulklc/covid19- 
  timeseries/master/countryReport/raw/rawReport.csv',
            stringsAsFactors = FALSE)

  yesterday <- function() Sys.Date() - 1L
  yesterday()
 # [1] "if it doesn't work yesterday()-1  do it"
```

I created the function of yesterday.

There are region, death and recovered sections in the df dataset.

The thing he wants your help is this.

To find the country that reported the most deaths in the continent, compared to yesterday in the DF data set

According to yesterday in the DF data set, find the country that reported the most recovered on the continent.

so what I want as output.

Date            countryName           region         death             recovered

2020/05/05   İtaly(sample)      Europe       **600**(sample)     50

2020/05/05   Spain(sample)      Europe       200(sample)     **580**

2020/05/05   China(sample)      Asia          **1200**           80

2020/05/05    Japan(sample)     Asia           400            **780**

..

..

..

countries and data are given as examples.

one line of death.
a row recovered.

required for each region.

There are 5 regions. It becomes 10 lines.

Answer (score 1):

This output is 10 rows (2 for each region) as you requested, but recognize that the United States for example reported both the most deaths and the most recoveries in the Americas region.  That means it appears twice.  This is similarly true of Iran and Australia, so there are only 7 unique rows.

```
library(tidyverse)
death_df <- df %>%
  filter(as.Date(day) == yesterday()) %>%
  group_by(region) %>%
  filter(death == max(death)) %>%
  select(Date = day,
         countryName,
         region,
         death,
         recovered)

recovered_df <- df %>%
  filter(as.Date(day) == yesterday()) %>%
  group_by(region) %>%
  filter(recovered == max(recovered)) %>%
  select(Date = day,
         countryName,
         region,
         death,
         recovered)

full_df <- bind_rows(death_df, recovered_df)
full_df
# A tibble: 10 x 5
# Groups:   region [5]
   Date       countryName    region   death recovered
   <chr>      <chr>          <chr>    <int>     <int>
 1 2020/05/05 Australia      Oceania     96      5889
 2 2020/05/05 Algeria        Africa     470      2067
 3 2020/05/05 United Kingdom Europe   29427         0
 4 2020/05/05 Iran           Asia      6340     80475
 5 2020/05/05 United States  Americas 72241    199684
 6 2020/05/05 Australia      Oceania     96      5889
 7 2020/05/05 Spain          Europe   25613    154718
 8 2020/05/05 Iran           Asia      6340     80475
 9 2020/05/05 United States  Americas 72241    199684
10 2020/05/05 South Africa   Africa     148      2746
```